# postgresql table set lock at some values

Tags: postgresql

It is possible to create table where for example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS router (
    id       BIGSERIAL     PRIMARY KEY
,   name_1   BOOLEAN       NOT NULL     DEFAULT FALSE
,   name_2   BOOLEAN       NOT NULL     DEFAULT FALSE
,   name_3   BOOLEAN       NOT NULL     DEFAULT FALSE
,   name_4   BOOLEAN       NOT NULL     DEFAULT FALSE
,   name_5   BOOLEAN       NOT NULL     DEFAULT FALSE
);
```

And with this table i would use something like lock to prevent of put more than 1 true value bettwen name_1 - name_5. For example if true value exist in name_1 is impossible to put something in name_2 - name_5. If exists in name_3 is impposible to put name_1,2,4 and 5

Comment: For the note, bigserial is really ambitious. The ~2 billion you get from usuing a plain serial are usually more than enough (not to mention faster) unless you're planning to scale like facebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a check constraint:

```
check (name_1 and not name_2 and not ...
     or name_2 and not name_1 and not ...
     or ...)
```

(There probably are shorter ways to express the boolean expression, but that's the gist of it.)

Comment: You can cast boolean to int and check if `sum = 1`

Comment: hmm but how about same example but with varchar/char or text ??

Comment: Same kind of thing, e.g.: `name_1 = 'foo' and name_2 is null and ...`